# Agrupar por mês (em cada coluna) SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Estou utilizando o codigo abaixo para fazer a coluna do mês de Janeiro, porém não achei uma forma de retornar o mês de fevereiro ao lado.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '20%' 
    THEN 'TALHA CORRENTE'
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '21%' 
    THEN 'TALHA CABO DE AÇO'
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '22%' 
    THEN 'PONTE ROLANTE'
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '23%'
    THEN 'SISTEMA LCS'
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '25%' 
    THEN 'MONOVIA'
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '27%'
    THEN 'GUINDASTE'
    ELSE 'OUTROS'
    END  AS 'EQUIPAMENTO',

    SUM(VLRUNIT * ITE.QTDNEG) AS JANEIRO

FROM

TGFCAB CAB
INNER JOIN TGFITE ITE ON CAB.NUNOTA = ITE.NUNOTA
INNER JOIN TGFPRO PRO ON ITE.CODPROD = PRO.CODPROD

WHERE 
CAB.AD_LIBERACAO_INTERNA BETWEEN '01/01/2021' AND '31/01/2021' AND CODTIPOPER IN (39,87,3100) AND AD_PEDIDO_CANCELADO IS NULL

GROUP BY 
    CASE 
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '20%' 
    THEN 'TALHA CORRENTE'
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '21%' 
    THEN 'TALHA CABO DE AÇO'
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '22%' 
    THEN 'PONTE ROLANTE'
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '23%'
    THEN 'SISTEMA LCS'
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '25%' 
    THEN 'MONOVIA'
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '27%'
    THEN 'GUINDASTE'
    ELSE 'OUTROS'
    END
```

O RESULTADO É O DO  DA IMAGEM  ABAIXO

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: acho que poderia agrupar só pelo código sem o case: `GROUP BY CODGRUPOPROD`. Sobre o mês, precisa também agrupar para trazer os valores separados, por exemplo adicionar ao select  e ao group by `YEAR(CAB.AD_LIBERACAO_INTERNA), MONTH(CAB.AD_LIBERACAO_INTERNA)`

Comment: Sobre o case no codgrupoprod é pela questão da descrição do grupo, agora sobre o mês, ele teria que agrupar o valor , dentro daquele mês na" coluna" , quando utilizo month ele agrupo por linha.

Comment: pra ajudar mais precisa ter um exemplo dos dados... consegue adicionar na pergunta ou montar um exemplo do sqlfiddle.com por exemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Isto deve funcionar , CASE por mês , talvez uma *function* do mysql ou sql-server (qual BD é ?) tipo MONTH , EXTRACT fique melhor

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '20%' 
    THEN 'TALHA CORRENTE'
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '21%' 
    THEN 'TALHA CABO DE AÇO'
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '22%' 
    THEN 'PONTE ROLANTE'
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '23%'
    THEN 'SISTEMA LCS'
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '25%' 
    THEN 'MONOVIA'
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '27%'
    THEN 'GUINDASTE'
    ELSE 'OUTROS'
    END  AS 'EQUIPAMENTO',

    SUM(CAB.AD_LIBERACAO_INTERNA BETWEEN '01/01/2021' AND '31/01/2021' THEN (VLRUNIT * ITE.QTDNEG) ELSE 0 END) JANEIRO,
    SUM(CAB.AD_LIBERACAO_INTERNA BETWEEN '01/02/2021' AND '28/02/2021' THEN (VLRUNIT * ITE.QTDNEG) ELSE 0 END) FEVEREIRO,
    /*REPETE AS LINHAS PARA OS MESES*/
 

FROM

TGFCAB CAB
INNER JOIN TGFITE ITE ON CAB.NUNOTA = ITE.NUNOTA
INNER JOIN TGFPRO PRO ON ITE.CODPROD = PRO.CODPROD

WHERE 
CAB.AD_LIBERACAO_INTERNA BETWEEN '01/01/2021' AND '31/12/2021' AND CODTIPOPER IN (39,87,3100) AND AD_PEDIDO_CANCELADO IS NULL

GROUP BY 
    CASE 
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '20%' 
    THEN 'TALHA CORRENTE'
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '21%' 
    THEN 'TALHA CABO DE AÇO'
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '22%' 
    THEN 'PONTE ROLANTE'
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '23%'
    THEN 'SISTEMA LCS'
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '25%' 
    THEN 'MONOVIA'
    WHEN CODGRUPOPROD LIKE '27%'
    THEN 'GUINDASTE'
    ELSE 'OUTROS'
    END
```